# Objective-C : enum like Java (int values and many others for each enum)

Tags: java, objective-c, enums, global

In Java, you can make an enum having multiples values.
In objective-C, this cannot be done easily.
I've read many pages about this but I didn't found anything satisfying that would allow me to use enums by a simple way and to **keep the enum declaration and their different values in the same file**.

I would like to write something like this in a enums.h :

```
// ========================================
typedef enum {eRED, eGREEN, eBLUE} ColorEnum;
int colorValues[] = { 0xFF0000, 0x00FF00, 0x0000FF };
NSArray *colorNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Red color", @"light green", @"Deep blue", nil];
// ========================================
```

and be able to use thoses global variables to manage my stuff anywhere like :

```
int color = colorValues[eRED];
```

But I don't know how to write this.
I have compile errors like "ColorValues" is defines many times.
Or if I just use "static", I have many "ColorValues" not used in .m file...

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tryed the following thing that works like a charm :

## in enums.h

```
@interface enums
    // here, the enum and its values are in the same place.

    typedef enum {eRED, eGREEN, eBLUE} ColorEnum;
    #define kColourValue  { 0xFF0000, 0x00FF00, 0x0000FF }
    extern int colourValues[];
@end
```

## in enums.m

```
@implementation enums
    int colorValues[] = kColourValue;
@end
```

And you have a perfect Java style implementation of enums in Objective-C.
Wow, two weeks of searches....

Answer (score 1):

You're close - the problem is that you put the definition of your array in the header file, where multiple compilation units end up duplicating it.  Put your middle line:

```
int colorValues[] = { 0xFF0000, 0x00FF00, 0x0000FF };
```

into one of your `.m` files, and change the header to read:

```
extern int colourValues[];
```

You'll need to do something similar with `colorNames`.  Change the header to:

```
extern NSArray *colorNames;
```

And then declare the actual object and initialize it in a `.m` file.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. If I put the middle line into a .m file, the enum and its corresponding values won't be in the same file ?

Comment: @Olivier, you can use a `#define` to fix that if you want to.  I'm not sure your intended design is a good idea to begin with, though.

Comment: Not sure the design is perfect, of course, but sometimes it may be the price to pay to work with a prehistoric language. Keeping same things at the same place is in my opinion a good way to keep the code clear and most of all, as bug free as possible.

Comment: @Olivier: Java & Objective-C are just two different languages we have to cope with. I'm also coming from Java and learning Objective-C. I also have issues with the syntax and this header files I've forgotten since I learnt C and C++ some decades ago...
We just have to "tame" this language as we would do with a puppy, accepting his differences and taking the power out of it!
Happy New Year and Happy Coding!

Comment: @LudoMC : You said it :-) Not the same languages. But for the moment, I only see leaks, not a lot of power... And if there are some, it must be great to balance the leaks :-)  Happy New Year to you too, may great code comes up for you in 2011 on the AppStore ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with the enum. It's *defining* variables in a header (rather than just declaring them) that's the problem. Just declare them in the header and move the implementation to an implementation file.

Also, you can't write `[NSArray arrayWithObjects…]` outside of a method. Only static initializers (that is, values that can be determined at compile time) are allowed there, whereas messages like that are only resolved at runtime. The solution is to move the assignment into an initialization function (e.g. `init` for a singleton or `initialize` for a class).

Comment: OK... I plan to write : #define kMyColorValue blabla, bla, blablabla int he .h, then use thus #define in the.m so the enum and its corresponding values will be kept at the same place. I try...

Comment: @Oliver: I think you've misunderstood. What I'm saying is, you shouldn't write `int foo = 5` in a header. You'd write `extern int foo` in the header and then in an implementation file you'd write `int foo = 5`.

Comment: Yes, I understood (I think) what you said but it gave me another idea.

Comment: I found something interesting to solve the problem. See my next post.